# XPath is correct but doesn't find the web element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm new to Python and coding. I'm trying to pass an XPath in the form of an outside value inside `browser.find_element_by_xpath()`. I've used the XPath in the browser console and it is correct, I've also used `time.sleep()` in various places to make the web page is loaded but I get an error. My question, is it even possible to find the element with this code?

```
a=input()
b = a.split(",")

for i in range(len(b)):

    c = ("""'//a[@title="{}"]'""".format(b[i]));time.sleep(1)
    print(c)
    print(type(c))
    act1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath(c)
```

---

Error message:

> FLQV-7734
>
> '//a[@title="FFLQV-7734"]'
>
> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid
>   selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression
>   '//a[@title="FFLQV-7734"]' because of the following error: TypeError:
>   Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node
>   set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.   (Session
>   info: chrome=72.0.3626.81)   (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68
>   (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.14393 x86_64)

Comment: Please include the code and the webpage you are trying it on.

Comment: Web page wont be accesible to others, this is just a question

Comment: @CapsaCk The webpage may not be accessible but could you at least copy an extract of the html?

Comment: The markup on the page seems irrelevant. From the exception the XPath is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is telling you the XPath is not valid. I suspect it is the extra single quotes around your xpath:

```
"""'//a[@title="{}"]'"""
   ^                ^
```

This should probably work:

```
"""//a[@title="{}"]"""
```

Making the final line of code:

```
c = ("""//a[@title="{}"]""".format(b[i]));time.sleep(1)
```

Without the single quotes before the `//` and after the `]` character.